# Children's or YA novel (series?) that involves the dead guiding a living kid back to the land of the living through a desert

Tags: story-identification

There is now only ONE item left on my "tormenting me from childhood; I can't remember what this was" list.

Some kind of novel, possibly a series of short novels, appropriate for precocious elementary schoolers.

75% confident it involved crossing the land of the dead (I think the plot might've been a bunch of dead people trying to help the one living kid get back to the land of the living?).

Most salient memory: at one point, they were crossing a desert wasteland, and there was a huge storm with tornadoes and lightning, and the lightning struck the sand and turned it to glass.

It would've been available in a public library somewhere around 1990-1996.  '96 is an upper bound; it definitely wouldn't have been published after that point.

Stories it is NOT:

- Abhorsen series
- Homeward Bounders
- The Black Cauldron
- His Dark Materials
- The Secrets of Droon
- Gregor the Overlander
- Sunwing

Comment: Any chance you're thinking of the Ghostworld series? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55247/ya-series-about-alive-boy-sent-to-ghost-fantasy-world-by-ghost-to-prevent-him-fr

Comment: @E.Z.Hart I think that might be it!  Still waiting on the book to verify, but this looks extremely promising!  You should throw up an answer and I'll accept it as soon as I can, if it's right.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer. If it doesn't turn out to be right, I'll be curious to see  what else folks come up with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be the [Ghostworld series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/76454-ghostworld).

Details which fit:

1. Story takes place in a "land of the dead" (the titular Ghostworld)
2. One of the protagonists is living.
3. The first book was published in 1991, so it fits the timeline.
4. It's a series of novels.
5. The target age range fits (elementary/middle school)